# How to change an image bit depth?

Tags: java, opencv

I am using Mindtct (NBIS Software).
When I run the program, I got the following error:

> ERROR : read_and_decode_grayscale_image : D:\Users\Malik\Desktop\cd642acd\cd642acd_1\I1_S1.png : image depth : 24 != 8

The Mindtct is a tool used to extract fingerprints' minutiaes: it only accepts grayscale images with a DPI equals to 8bits, but I use a fingerprint sensor that apparently generates images with a DPI equals to 24 bits.

My question is: 
How can I change the image depth (reduce it from 24bits to 8bits) in JAVA (OpenCV) or C++ or even in another language?

```sh
./mindtct.exe -m1 $pathImage $imageNameResult
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to convert some three-channel ("color") image to a single-channel ("grayscale") image? There's the [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) function in OpenCV, and the proper Java API call might be `Imgproc.cvtColor(source, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`.

Comment: Can you try this using opencv




Mat result8u,gray;
result.convertTo(result8u,CV_8U);
cvtColor(result8u,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> First Method: (This version need the OpenCV .jar)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
   String file = "AbsolutePathToTheSRCImage2.png";
   Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(file);
   Mat dst = new Mat();
   Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
   Imgcodecs.imwrite("AbsolutePathToTheDSTImage2", dst);
}
```

If do not want to use OpenCV library, you can use the following classic method:

[image: Here is the mathematical formula of conversion]

> Second Method:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
WritableRaster rasterJPEG = image.getRaster();

for(int h=0; h<height; h++)
   for(int w=0; w<width; w++) {
      int[] p = new int[4];
       rasterJPEG.getPixel(w, h, p);
       p[0] = (int) (0.3 * p[0]);
       p[1] = (int) (0.59 * p[1]);
       p[2] = (int) (0.11 * p[2]);
       int y = p[0] + p[1] + p[2];
       raster.setSample(w,h,0,y);
    }
 return img;
```